# C Source to .Snap

Tags: packaging, c, snap

Source is in C. Requires multiple dependencies to successfully make.

This will not appear in the app-store. There is no GUI component. 
This application is designed to run on a specifically-configured embedded device.

No documentation seems to exist to bring C applications to snappy. 
Any thoughts or tutorials?

Goal is not to install multiple dependencies and have source on the target, but rather the source, dependencies, etc. are stored with the Server - simplifying a global update process by updating the server, and providing the fresh stuff to the IoT device.

Comment: Recommend closing issue. Snappy will not work for my device. Will use Yocto instead.

Answer (score 2):

We don't treat language specific case with snapcraft but rather build system. You surely are using a build system with your package, this one being autotools, make, cmake, qmake…

Snapcraft have `plugins` for those, and you can find demos for each plugins [in the snapcraft source tree](https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/tree/master/demos) (or installing `snapcraft-examples`).

If you look at [snapcraft.io tour](http://snapcraft.io/create/), the first example compiles some C code (GNU bash) using autotools: